# ApplicationInfo.java to Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-applicationinfo

I want the user's recently used applications to show up in a GridView. So far, I know I need to include this: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/src/com/example/android/home/ApplicationInfo.html

And I have the GridView setup in main.xml:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/Icons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="739px"
    android:layout_marginTop="42px"
    android:columnWidth="122px"
    android:horizontalSpacing="31px"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="42px" >

</GridView>
```

But how would I load the applications in that space?

Answer (score 0):

You would create a `ListAdapter` that wraps around your data model ("recently used applications") and can create the cells for your grid. An `ArrayAdapter` on your `List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo>` will probably do nicely.